# How to use AWS lambda to convert pdf files to .txt with python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pypdf, pdftotext

I need to automate the conversion of many pdf to text files using AWS lambda in python 3.7

I've successfully converted pdf files using poppler/pdftotext, tika, and PyPDF2 on my own machine. However tika times out or needs to run a java instance on a host machine which I'm not sure how to set up. pdftotext needs poppler and all the solutions for running that on lambda seems to be outdated or I'm just not familiar enough with binarys to make sense of that solution. PyPDF2 seems the most promising but testing throws an error.

The code and error I'm getting for PyPDF2 is as follows:

```
pdf_file = open(s3.Bucket(my_bucket).download_file('test.pdf','test.pdf'),'rb')

  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.pdf.3F925aC8'",
  "errorType": "OSError",



and if I try to reference it directly,
pdf_file = open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + my_bucket + '/test.pdf', 'rb')

  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/test.pdf'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
```

Comment: Have you given your Lambda execution role permissions to access the S3 bucket?

Comment: Yeah, it has full s3 read/write permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS lambda only allows you to write into the /tmp folder, so you should download the file and put it in there

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are trying to write to a read-only filesystem. You are using the `download_file` method which tries to save the file to 'test.pdf' which fails. Try using `download_fileobj` [(link)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj) together with an in-memory buffer (e.g. `io.BytesIO`) instead. Then, feed that stream to PyPDF2.

Example:

```py
import io
[...]

pdf_stream = io.StringIO()
object.download_fileobj(pdf_stream)
pdf_obj = PdfFileReader(pdf_stream)

[...]
```